# Need clarification on what is called contravariant vectors in an article

Tags: vectors

For my own curiosity because I heard of it (it might help me one day) but I never studied it I am reading an [introduction of tensor calculus](ftp://www.iqimaging.com/USB_BackUp/Data/Articles/Relativity/Tensors/tensortutorialDullemond.pdf).

In the third paragraph of the 10th page we can read :

> The normal vectors are called ‘contravariant vectors’, because they
>   transform contrary to the basis vector columns.

I would like to be sure if by **normal** they are speaking about $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{v}'$ ?

I looked at the definition on the wikipedia page but I'm just learning about that for a hour and wikipedia is insane for me now.

Thank you in advance

Comment: It seems to me that by "normal", the authors mean "typical", i.e. the kind of vectors that you are already familiar with from Linear Algebra. There is no discussion of inner products at that point, so the more precise definition of normal ($\vec u$, $\vec v$ are normal w.r.t. an inner product iff $\langle\vec u,\vec v\rangle=0$) wouldn't make sense in context.

Comment: @kajelad thanks